# How to set th.action using data from a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

I have this hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="controllerName" name="controllerName" value="nnnn"/>
```

Which contains the controller name that will be called by the form.
And basically what I need to do is something like this:

```
<form role="form" 
      th:action="${controllerName} + @{/deleteAssignment}" 
      name="assignmentDeleteForm"
      id="assignmentDeleteForm" method="post">
</form>
```

I want to put the value I have on this hidden field into the th:action concatenated with the `@{/deleteAssignment}`.

This page is a modal, so I'm setting the hidden field like this on javascript:

```
modal.find('#controllerName').val(controller);
```

I can't set the action directly form javascript because it's losing the context and then it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<form role="form" 
      th:action="@{ + ${controllerName} + '/deleteAssignment'}" 
      name="assignmentDeleteForm"
      id="assignmentDeleteForm" method="post">
</form>
```